# STM32H750B configuring DMA to transfer from GPIO to RAM

Tags: stm32, gpio, ram, dma

on STM32F769i

I used DMA2 triggered by TIM1 to read data from GPIOB port like this
so timer1 counted and when it triggered DMA read data in circular mode from GPIOB into my buffer

```
#define SAMPLING_PORT GPIOB
#define MAX_SAMPLING_RAM 16*4

#define TIM1_PERIOD 16-1 //2 MHz at the end

uint32_t samplingRam[MAX_SAMPLING_RAM];

static void MX_TIM1_Init(void)
{
      //Init clock
      RCC->APB2ENR |= RCC_APB2ENR_TIM1EN;

      TIM1->DIER = 0;
      TIM1->SR &= ~TIM_SR_UIF;
      TIM1->CNT = 0;
      TIM1->PSC = 0;
      TIM1->CR1 = TIM_CR1_URS;      //Enable update request source
      TIM1->ARR = TIM1_PERIOD;
      TIM1->CR2 = 0;
      TIM1->DIER = TIM_DIER_UDE;        //Enable update DMA request
      TIM1->EGR = TIM_EGR_UG;       //Generate an update event to reload timer registers
}

static void MX_DMA_Init(void)
{

  RCC->AHB1ENR |= RCC_AHB1ENR_DMA2EN; //Enable clock
  uint32_t dmaSize = DMA_PDATAALIGN_HALFWORD;

  DMA2_Stream5->CR = (DMA_SxCR_CHSEL_1 | DMA_SxCR_CHSEL_2) | dmaSize | DMA_SxCR_MINC | DMA_SxCR_CIRC; //Circular mode, memory increase, perihperal not increase
  DMA2_Stream5->M0AR = (uint32_t)samplingRam;//samplingRam;
  DMA2_Stream5->PAR  = (uint32_t)&(SAMPLING_PORT->IDR);
  DMA2_Stream5->NDTR = 16;//transferCount;// / transferSize;
  DMA2_Stream5->FCR = DMA_SxFCR_DMDIS | DMA_SxFCR_FTH;  //disable direct mode, set FIFO-threshold

}
```

Now I am trying to do the same using STM32H750B
at first I was very confused as I read that I cannot even do that using DMA, that I have to use BDMA for this, then I found out that I can use DMAMUX for this

So I tried doing this with DMAMUX

```
void SetupSamplingDMA(void *dataBuffer, uint32_t dataTransferCount)
{
    uint32_t dmaSize = CalcDMATransferSize();
    
    // Enable DMA (DMAMUX clocks is enabled automaticly)
    RCC->AHB1ENR |= RCC_AHB1ENR_DMA2EN;
    
    // Configure DMAMUX channel
    DMAMUX1_Channel0->CCR &= ~DMAMUX_CxCR_DMAREQ_ID; // clear DMAREQ_ID field
    DMAMUX1_Channel0->CCR = (DMAMUX_CxCR_DMAREQ_ID_0 & (8 << DMAMUX_CxCR_DMAREQ_ID_Pos)); // set DMAREQ_ID field to GPIOB request ID
    
    // Configure DMA stream
    DMA2_Stream5->CR = DMA_SxCR_MINC | DMA_SxCR_CIRC;
    DMA2_Stream5->PAR = (uint32_t)&(SAMPLING_PORT->IDR);
    DMA2_Stream5->M0AR = (uint32_t)samplingRam;         //buffer to transfer it to
    DMA2_Stream5->NDTR = 16;             // Number of data items to transfer (e.g., 16 for 16-bit samples)
    DMA2_Stream5->FCR = DMA_SxFCR_DMDIS | DMA_SxFCR_FTH; //disable direct mode, set FIFO-threshold
}
```

but sadly nothing works DMA2_Stream5->NDTR is always 0 (instead of being 16 and counting down to 0)

So does anyone know whats wrong? How can I read GPIOB with DMA on this board?
When porting code from STMF4 to F7 I never had problems like this :)

Thanks for Anwsering and Best Regards

Comment: You need to configure differnt DMA and DMAMUX. It is present in all new STMs

Comment: Where in memory is your `samplingRam` array located (what is its address)? If it's in the either ITCM or DTCM blocks at 0x00000000 or 0x20000000 then DMA won't work. You'll have to move it into one of the other blocks like AXISRAM at 0x24000000 (by editing your project's linker script or possibly using something like a `#pragma`, depending on your compiler).

Comment: @brhans good point. Standard stm linker script locates it there

Comment: @brhans thanks, but my samlingRam is at 0x2400028c 

I verified this with printf("Address of variable is: %p\n", &samplingRam);

I did not move it anywhere manualy

my STM32H750XBHX_FLASH.ld has this in it: 
MEMORY
{
  FLASH (rx)     : ORIGIN = 0x08000000, LENGTH = 128K
  DTCMRAM (xrw)  : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 128K
  RAM_D1 (xrw)   : ORIGIN = 0x24000000, LENGTH = 512K
  RAM_D2 (xrw)   : ORIGIN = 0x30000000, LENGTH = 288K
  RAM_D3 (xrw)   : ORIGIN = 0x38000000, LENGTH = 64K
  ITCMRAM (xrw)  : ORIGIN = 0x00000000, LENGTH = 64K
}

Answer (score 0):

1. Cache validate or
2. Cache off or
3. MPU setting (cache off) for dma buffer.

Comment: Byoungchol Park - Hi, Thanks for trying to help. However at the moment, the answer is very short and only says the "what" without explaining any "why" or "how". Can you [edit] your answer to add more details, to help readers understand *why* those 3 points are the answer, and *how* they solve the original issue? I expect that adding more information to explain your answer will make it more helpful for the future. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

a)
You have to use "paired" DMA stream and DMAMUX. Reference manual paragraph **17.3.2 DMAMUX1 mapping** says that DMAMUX1 channel 8 routing request to DMA2 stream 0. For your stream 5 you have to use DMAMUX1 channel 13 (if i count correctly).

b)
DMAMUX1_Channelx->CCR - you have to write there DMA request ID. Request from your timer. Look at **Table 121. DMAMUX1** in reference manual and search for TIM1 requests (11 to 17).

c) Be sure that you've enabled clock for DMAMUX, DMA, GPIOB, TIM...